# Setting up Google Accounts for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to GCP and trying to set it up for our startup. We are not using GSuite or Cloud Identity. We have one Google account we have setup for billing. My question is around how many Google Accounts should we setup for GCP access for our team (not endusers). Is it best practice to create one for each customer/application or is it better to just to create one master Google account?

We would be creating a project per application/environment.

Any advice or recommendations would be most appreciated.

Comment: When you say GCP access, did you mean both your teams and endusers ?

Comment: Just for our teams. I'm trying to work out should there be only 1 google account which has all projects or we split it up. I couldn't find anything related to this in their documentation.

Comment: You might need to create Organization node in that case which can have 1 or 2 admins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own a domain name, it's free to create a Cloud Identity and thus an organisation. Each user in your team need to have a Google identity (and it's better if it's centrally managed in Cloud Identity for example). Think to the people movement: new team member, resign, creation of groups for simplifying the access management,...

Comment: Great thanks, I'll take a look and see if I can set this up.